# nodejs: setImmediate callback executed after setTimeout(fn, 0) inconsistent with the nodejs doc describes

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, event-loop

This is what the [Node document said](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg)

> ### setImmediate(callback, [arg], [...])
>
> To schedule the "immediate" execution of callback after I/O events callbacks and **before setTimeout and setInterval** . Returns an immediateObject for possible use with clearImmediate(). Optionally you can also pass arguments to the callback.

However, if you run the following code you'll find the result not as expected.

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.time('start');
setImmediate(function () {
  console.log('immediate');
  console.timeEnd('start');
});

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('timeout');
  console.timeEnd('start');
}, 0);

process.nextTick(function () {
  console.log('nextTick');
  console.timeEnd('start');
});
```

The output is the following, setImmediate callback just executed **after** setTimeout callback. So do I misunderstand something in the Node document?

> nextTick
>   start: 2ms
>   timeout
>   start: 2ms
>   immediate
>   start: 2ms

Comment: Is is not a bug,  but depends on when you call `setImmediate`, `setTimeout`, `nextTick`: see [Node Issues: setTimeout(fn, 0) running before setImmediate](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6034) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks! It is the right answer.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance

Answer (score 3):

As Node.js doc says:

> [setimmediate-vs-settimeout](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout)
>   The order in which the timers are executed will vary depending on the context in which they are called. If both are called from within the main module, then timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).
>   For example, if we run the following script which is not within an I/O cycle (i.e. the main module), the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of the process:

Why ?.

Every event in node.js is driven by `uv_run()` function of libuv. Partial Code

```
int uv_run(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_run_mode mode) {
  int timeout;
  int r;
  int ran_pending;

  r = uv__loop_alive(loop);
  if (!r)
    uv__update_time(loop);

  while (r != 0 && loop->stop_flag == 0) {
    uv__update_time(loop);
    uv__run_timers(loop);
    ran_pending = uv__run_pending(loop);
    uv__run_idle(loop);
    uv__run_prepare(loop);

    ......

    uv__io_poll(loop, timeout);
    uv__run_check(loop);
    uv__run_closing_handles(loop);
    ............
```

So As explained by the node.js Doc, we can match each Phase of the event loop in the code.

**Timer Phase** `uv__run_timers(loop);`

**I/O Callback** `ran_pending = uv__run_pending(loop);`

**idle/ prepare** `uv__run_idle(loop); uv__run_prepare(loop);`

**poll**  `uv__io_poll(loop, timeout);`

**check** `uv__run_check(loop);`

**close callbacks**  `uv__run_closing_handles(loop);`

#### More than phase

But if we see the code closely before the loop goes to timer phase, it calls 
`uv__update_time(loop);`  to initialize the loop time.

```
void uv_update_time(uv_loop_t* loop) {
   uv__update_time(loop);
}
```

What happens is `uv__update_time(loop)` calls an function `uv__hrtime`

```
UV_UNUSED(static void uv__update_time(uv_loop_t* loop)) {
  /* Use a fast time source if available.  We only need millisecond precision.
   */
  loop->time = uv__hrtime(UV_CLOCK_FAST) / 1000000;
}
```

This call to `uv__hrtime` is platform dependent and is cpu-time-consuming work as it makes system
call to [clock_gettime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). It's is impacted by other application running on the machine.

```
#define NANOSEC ((uint64_t) 1e9)
uint64_t uv__hrtime(uv_clocktype_t type) {
  struct timespec ts;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
  return (((uint64_t) ts.tv_sec) * NANOSEC + ts.tv_nsec);
}
```

Once this is returned Timer phase is called in the event loop.

```
void uv__run_timers(uv_loop_t* loop) {
  ...
  for (;;) {
    ....
    handle = container_of(heap_node, uv_timer_t, heap_node);
    if (handle->timeout > loop->time)
      break;
      ....
    uv_timer_again(handle);
    handle->timer_cb(handle);
  }
}
```

The callback in the Timer phase is run if the current time of loop is greater than the timeout. 
One more important things to note is `setTimeout` when set to `0` is internally converted to `1`.
Also as the `hr_time` return time in Nanoseconds, this behaviour as shown by the `timeout_vs_immediate.js` becomes more explanatory now.

If the preparation before the first loop took more than `1ms` then the `Timer` Phase calls the callback associated with it. If it's is less than `1ms` Event-loop continues to next phase and runs the `setImmediate` callback in check phase of the loop and `setTimeout` in the
next tick of the loop.